# Different array output between print_r and foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My PHP code `print_r($array_ranking)` gives me a different output than

```php
foreach ($array_ranking as $row) {
echo "NAAM : " . $row['Familienaam'] . " - ";
            echo "RANK : " . $row['PTN_RANK'] . " - ";
            echo "PTN : " . $row['PTN'] . "<br>";
}
```

I marked the differences in bold.

Former output:
array ( 0 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'SINNAEVE', 'Voornaam' => 'Thierry', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA19', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC DE DEKEN', 'LIC_NR' => 9637, 'TSP' => 40, 'GSP' => '305', 'BRT' => '133', 'MOY' => '2.2932', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '13', 'PTN_RANK' => 1, ), 1 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'DE SMET', 'Voornaam' => 'Wim', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA09', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC DE LEUG', 'LIC_NR' => 4650, 'TSP' => 45, 'GSP' => '255', 'BRT' => '100', 'MOY' => '2.5500', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '12', 'PTN_RANK' => 2, ), 2 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'CEULEMANS', 'Voornaam' => 'Jan', 'Stamnummer' => 'AL24', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC BILJART-WORLD', 'LIC_NR' => 9558, 'TSP' => 40, 'GSP' => '244', 'BRT' => '101', 'MOY' => '2.4158', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '11', 'PTN_RANK' => 3, ), 3 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'VERELST', 'Voornaam' => 'François', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA09', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC DE LEUG', 'LIC_NR' => 8701, 'TSP' => 40, 'GSP' => '188', 'BRT' => '113', 'MOY' => '1.6637', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '10', 'PTN_RANK' => 4, ), 4 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'LOOYMANS', 'Voornaam' => 'Marcel', 'Stamnummer' => 'AT82', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'KBC BILJARTVRIENDEN TURNHOUT', 'LIC_NR' => 9155, 'TSP' => 50, 'GSP' => '295', 'BRT' => '139', 'MOY' => '2.1223', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '10', 'PTN_RANK' => 5, ), 5 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'HOREMANS', 'Voornaam' => 'Peter', 'Stamnummer' => 'AL35', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC DE PLAKKERS', 'LIC_NR' => 8190, 'TSP' => 50, 'GSP' => '285', 'BRT' => '148', 'MOY' => '1.9257', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '10', 'PTN_RANK' => 6, ), 6 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'SAERENS', 'Voornaam' => 'Marc', 'Stamnummer' => 'AL31', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'KBC REAL', 'LIC_NR' => 9880, 'TSP' => 40, 'GSP' => '310', 'BRT' => '164', 'MOY' => '1.8902', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '10', 'PTN_RANK' => 7, ), 7 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'VERMEESCH', 'Voornaam' => 'Dirk', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA18', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC SALAMANDER', 'LIC_NR' => 7708, 'TSP' => 45, 'GSP' => '232', 'BRT' => '141', 'MOY' => '1.6454', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '10', 'PTN_RANK' => 8, ), 8 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'HEIRBAUT', 'Voornaam' => 'Gert', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA09', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC DE LEUG', 'LIC_NR' => 7433, 'TSP' => 45, 'GSP' => '279', 'BRT' => '147', 'MOY' => '1.8980', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '8', 'PTN_RANK' => 9, ), 9 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'GOLDBERG', 'Voornaam' => 'Robert', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA15', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC SCHIL-DORP', 'LIC_NR' => 9159, 'TSP' => 45, 'GSP' => '284', 'BRT' => '166', 'MOY' => '1.7108', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '8', 'PTN_RANK' => 10, ), 10 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'BORREMANS', 'Voornaam' => 'Mario', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA09', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC DE LEUG', 'LIC_NR' => 9918, 'TSP' => 45, 'GSP' => '257', 'BRT' => '116', 'MOY' => '2.2155', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '8', 'PTN_RANK' => 11, ), 11 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'MICHIELSEN', 'Voornaam' => 'Willy', 'Stamnummer' => 'AT84', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC DE COECK', 'LIC_NR' => 7095, 'TSP' => 40, 'GSP' => '207', 'BRT' => '150', 'MOY' => '1.3800', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '7', 'PTN_RANK' => 12, ), 12 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'VERHULST', 'Voornaam' => 'Thomas', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA92', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC DE MIDDEL', 'LIC_NR' => 9674, 'TSP' => 45, 'GSP' => '263', 'BRT' => '136', 'MOY' => '1.9338', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '7', 'PTN_RANK' => 13, ), 13 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'VERELST', 'Voornaam' => 'Frank', 'Stamnummer' => 'AL21', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC OP DE MEIR', 'LIC_NR' => 8814, 'TSP' => 46, 'GSP' => '250', 'BRT' => '169', 'MOY' => '1.4793', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '6', 'PTN_RANK' => 14, ), 14 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'VAN MENSEL', 'Voornaam' => 'Marcel', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA18', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC SALAMANDER', 'LIC_NR' => 7568, 'TSP' => 45, 'GSP' => '203', 'BRT' => '123', 'MOY' => '1.6504', 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '4', 'PTN_RANK' => 15, ), 15 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'MARIEN', 'Voornaam' => 'Rowan', 'Stamnummer' => 'AA99', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'BC HEMIKSEM', 'LIC_NR' => 5009, 'TSP' => 50, 'GSP' => '0', 'BRT' => '0', 'MOY' => NULL, 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '2', 'PTN_RANK' => 16, ), 16 => array ( 'Familienaam' => 'DEBIE', 'Voornaam' => 'Louis', 'Stamnummer' => 'AL29', 'CLUB_NAAM' => 'GROBBENDONKSE BC', 'LIC_NR' => 8790, 'TSP' => 40, 'GSP' => '0', 'BRT' => '0', 'MOY' => NULL, 'MOY_RANK' => 0, 'PTN' => '0', 'PTN_RANK' => 17, ), )
Latter ouput :

> NAAM : SINNAEVE - RANK : 1 - PTN : 13
> NAAM : DE SMET - RANK : 2 - PTN : 12
> NAAM : CEULEMANS - RANK : 3 - PTN : 11
> NAAM : VERELST - RANK : 4 - PTN : 10
> NAAM : LOOYMANS - RANK : 5 - PTN : 10
> NAAM : HOREMANS - RANK : 6 - PTN : 10
> NAAM : SAERENS - RANK : 7 - PTN : 10
> NAAM : VERMEESCH - RANK : 8 - PTN : 10
> NAAM : HEIRBAUT - RANK : 9 - PTN : 8
> NAAM : GOLDBERG - RANK : 10 - PTN : 8
> NAAM : BORREMANS - RANK : 11 - PTN : 8
> NAAM : MICHIELSEN - RANK : 12 - PTN : 7
> NAAM : VERHULST - RANK : 13 - PTN : 7
> NAAM : VERELST - RANK : 14 - PTN : 6
> NAAM : VAN MENSEL - RANK : 15 - PTN : 4
> **NAAM : MARIEN - RANK : 16 - PTN : 2
> NAAM : MARIEN - RANK : 16 - PTN : 2**

No idea what this triggers. All suggestions more than welcome.

Comment: So the user with family name MARIEN gets shown twice, and the one with family name DEBIE gets dropped completely ...? The code you have shown really doesn't explain that (which we could easily _verify_, if you provide your input data in the form of a `var_export`, or as JSON, please), there must be more going on than what you have shown us already.

Comment: Please improve the format and provide a [mre].

Comment: Required reading: [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). (Your question has an [edit] button, in case you hadn't spotted it).

Comment: And yeah there's nothing in what you've shown to prove how that could happen. As CBroe says, please provide the output of var_export($array_ranking) so we can see the original $array_ranking data in a usable form, and therefore test your assertion. Then if it reproduces the the problem we'll be able to understand it and offer a solution. If it doesn't demonstrate the problem, we'll ask you to go back and build a [mre] which does. See also [ask] for general guidance on asking a useful question, too. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry guys, not used to posting things here. How exactly do I post a JSON or var_export best?

Comment: The array I posted is the way it outputs as a result of the print_r. How can I provide you with more data so you can help me? I read the articles about formatting posts, but I don't see what I can do more for the moment. Really stuck here...

Comment: `echo json_encode($array_ranking, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` or `echo var_export($array_ranking, true);`.  Be aware, that print_r may "cut" data to simplify.

Comment: I edited my question. Is this a better format of the array?

Comment: Use the markdown syntax or the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Can't you just copy/paste the array above? Anyway, sorry to have bothered you. I'll take my question elsewhere. Asking easy questions is maybe too difficult for me.